# How does the recur keyword finds out what is the recursion point?

Tags: clojure

I wrote the following code to practice how to write loops in clojure:

```
(ns tutorial.loops)

(defn testing_loops
  "A function to test loops"
  []
  (loop [x 0]
    (when (< x 10)
      (println x)
      (recur (inc x))
      )
    )
  )

(testing_loops)
```

My question is, how does the **recur** keyword know what the recursion point is?

How did it decide that the **loop** is the recursion point and not the function **testing_loops**?

**EDIT:**

Why can't the **when** be a recursion point?

Answer (score 1):

The first "parent" loop or fn is the recur target.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Why can't the "when" cannot be the parent?

Comment: See documentation: https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#recur

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't the when be a recursion point

the thing is, this whole `recur` stuff is the clojure compiler's workaround of the lack of tail call elimination (in jvm?)

So. There are exactly 2 points where `recur` passes control to:
The function's top level e.g. `(defn f [x] (recur (inc x)))` or closest parent `loop` body if any (including some rare macros, using `loop` under the hood, like [go-loop](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/go-loop) from core.async). That said, i'd emphasize: **this is purely a design decision of language/compiler creators**, so that's why no other forms can be `recur`red to. Just a rule to remember. that's it